# Pandas: how to assign the information from one dataframe to another based on the size of the information?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes  `df1` and `df2` like the following ones

```
df1
      val
0      -2
1      -1
2      -5
3      -2
4      -4
5      -7
6      -7
7      -3
8      -6

df2
      Name Year size
0     Marc 2010  2
1     Marc 2011  1
2     Eric 2010  1
3     Eric 2011  1
4     Sara 2010  2
5     Sara 2011  2
```

I would like to update the information of `df1` based on the information from `df2` in the following way:

```
df1
      val   Name   Year
0     -2    Marc   2010
1     -1    Marc   2010
2     -5    Marc   2011
3     -2    Eric   2010
4     -4    Eric   2011
5     -7    Sara   2010
6     -7    Sara   2010
7     -3    Sara   2011
8     -6    Sara   2011
```

P.S. I can't join the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df1.join(df2.reindex(df2.index.repeat(df2["size"])).reset_index(drop=True)).drop("size", axis=1)
   Val   Name  Year
0   -2   Marc  2010
1   -1   Marc  2010
2   -5   Marc  2011
3   -2   Eric  2010
4   -4   Eric  2011
5   -7  Ssara  2010
6   -7  Ssara  2010
7   -3  Ssara  2011
8   -6  Ssara  2011
```

Comment: I didn't know that [`pd.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) works with a list (0 to drop) of repetitions. Nice solution.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny - I learned this from SO a while ago too ;)